# Django: manage.py runserver после выдало такую ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Переустановил Django даже сменил имя пользователя на англ не помогает(

Comment: Как вы его устанавливали?

Answer (score 0):

При установке python Вы ставили галочку на PATH? Установите Django через терминал с помощью pip (незабудьте обновить pip)

Comment: СПС добавил в переменные среды путь к джанго